# How to achieve this style of border? css only preferred

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get header effect like this:

[image]

I want the dotted border along the bottom of the element, with the background the same color as the dots.
I've tried looking up how to set up a border offset but haven't found anything that works for the look I'm trying to achieve. I've tried using an outline as well, only to find that the outline property can't be specific to a single edge.

Comment: It sounds as though you've tried things and researched your question, but you've left the fruits of all that effort out of your question. You can greatly improve your question by sharing what you've tried.

Comment: To start, you could use `border-bottom: 1px dotted #f00`. Add your header HTML and existing CSS to your question.

Comment: I don't see any dots in that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a div underneath the box with a border-style of dashed:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box-border"></div>

.box-border{
    border-bottom:dashed 3px red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oo31w9x4/

Comment: @dindae You're welcome. Don't hesitate to click the checkmark ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use box-shadow as background.

```css
div {
  color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 1000px 0px red;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div>the header</div>
```